# My function won't add a paragraph to the document

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a button add a paragraph from a text input

http://jsfiddle.net/3gf7tqvo/

JavaScript:

```
function addParagraph() {
    var textinput = document.getElementById("pageinput");
    var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    newParagraph.textContent = textinput;
    document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(newParagraph);
}

document.getElementById('a').onClick = addParagraph;
```

HTML:

```
<button id='a'>Click Me!</button>
<input type="text" id="pageinput">
<div id='updateDiv'></div>
```

ฺBut after an hour of frustration, I can't see why it just won't add the paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two little mistakes:

1. Use `textinput.value` instead of `textinput` like so:

   ```
   newParagraph.textContent = textinput.value;
   ```
2. Write `onclick` instead of `onClick` like so:

   ```
   document.getElementById('a').onclick = addParagraph;
   ```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3gf7tqvo/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the value of text:

```js
function addParagraph() {
  var textinput = document.getElementById("pageinput");
  var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
  newParagraph.textContent = textinput.value;//here take the value of input text
  document.getElementById("updateDiv").appendChild(newParagraph);
}

//document.getElementById('a').oncClick = addParagraph; onclick is the corect syntax
```

```html
<button id='a' onclick="addParagraph(); return false;">Click Me!</button>
<div id='updateDiv'></div>
<input type="text" id="pageinput">
```

p.s. Always like more to add events in element.